# Existence of Elementary Antiderivatives

Tags: integration

A version of **Liouville's criterion** states that: Choose functions $~f~$ and $~g~$ such that $~f≠0~$ and $~g~$ is non-constant. Then, the function $~f(x)e^{g(x)}~$ can be integrated in elementary terms iff there exits a rational function $~R(x)~$ such that $$~R'(x)+g'(x)R(x)=f(x)~.$$
I think I may have used the criteria wrongly, since it gives contradictory results?

I considered the function $~e^x~$, which obviously has an elementary anti-derivative. Then, I let $~f=1~$ and $~g=x~$, so the $~1^{st}~$ order differential equation I had to solve was $~R'(x)+R(x)=1~$.

The general solution to this D.E. is $~R(x)=Ce^{-x}+1~$, where $~c~$ is an arbitrary constant.

However, $~R(x)~$ is clearly not a rational function, so I don't know where my misconception lies.

Is it because Louville's criteria considers complex-valued functions of the real variable $~x~$?

Comment: What are the conditions for f and g? Are they real, complex or rational?

Comment: f and g are complex valued functions.

Comment: $R(x)=1$ is a rational solution.

Comment: Well, yes, but why must we restrict R(x) to 1? Or does the criteria hold as long as there exists some c and x such that R(x) is rational?